# Why do SMPTE colour bars block part of Ryou's face in episode 13?

Tags: anime-de-wakaru-shinryounaika

In the beginning of episode 13 of [*Anime de Wakaru Shinryounaika*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/27911/Anime_de_Wakaru_Shinryounaika), Ryou's face is partially covered by a triangle with the SMPTE colour bars:

[image: Ryou's blocked face, when the characters are introducing themselves]

At first, Ryou just keeps talking as if everything is as expected. But then he seems to notice this blocking his face, and so he tries to step away from behind this triangle so that he isn't blocked by it, though the triangle follows him around:

[image: Ryou stepping to the left to dodge the triangle]
[image: Ryou stepping to the right to dodge the triangle]

In either situation, neither Asuna nor Himeru seem to paid any mind to the triangle with the SMPTE colours.

Then, it simply goes away, and it's as if it never happened. No one makes mention of it again, nor is it explained.

**Was this a reference to something else I missed?

What was the meaning of having partially blocked Ryou's face with a triangle with the SMPTE colour bars?**

Comment: Just to assert that Ryou is not the "main character" of the series in a comical and humourous way. Similar treatment can be seen in other episodes.

Comment: What do you mean by similar treatment? I didn't catch any of it up until now? Does it only happen in the subsequent episodes?

Comment: The nurse acts as if she closes the clinic early at the beginning of the last episode, and I remember there are other instances where the doctor appearance on screen is obstructed. I guess you see more of this in the later episodes.

Answer (score 2):

They don't explain this well in the manga either (they are irregularly-shaped panels), but it's assumed to be related to Himeru's social anxiety from the previous episode. It's possible that this is a way for her to cope with speaking to Ryou, by imagining his face to be covered.

[image: 第35回「睡眠時無呼吸症候群に気をつけて！」]